# many-to-many relationship in database design

Tags: database, many-to-many, relationship

I currently have a database with two tables called Articles and Tags . In order to allow articles to be in multiple categories i have a many to many relationship. Is it a mistake to have such a design in terms of performance? or should i remove the relationship between these two table and add a third table as a bridge (articlesTags)?

Comment: How did you create a many-to-many relationship without the use of an articlesTags table?

Comment: If you have a many-to-many relationship, you need the third table to represent - there isn't a sensible alternative.  Your nearest approach might be a SET structure in each table - if your DBMS supports that.  But there typically isn't much inter-table checking on such types - the separate table is necessary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with having a many-to-many relationship, you'll just need to create a [Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) (which is what it sounds like you're referring to with `articlesTags`) to facilitate that relationship.

Comment: Also known as an Intersection table.

Comment: I want a sensible abstraction for this.  This self-created and self-managed junction table malarkey has gone on for way too long.

Comment: @APC or a Join table (at least in JPA)

Comment: Oh, and according to Wikipedia, also cross-reference table, bridge table, join table, map table, intersection table, linking table, many-to-many resolver, link table, pairing table, pivot table, or association table. Can't have too many names I suppose :p

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom - thanks: I'll memorise that list for the next time when I say "intersection table" and get a blank look in response.  As for "Join table" don't like that term.  It's a relational database, they're all join (well joinable) tables.

Comment: I think association table is the clearest in its intent, and many-to-many resolver has the most Hollywoodish sound :)

Answer (score 7):

You're seeing the difference between a conceptual database design (the N:N relationship) and it's physical realisation.  No matter how you model your N:N relationship, you'll need the aforementioned Junction Table to make it work.

There's nothing wrong with modeling a real world relationship as close to the real world as you can as a general statement.  Clarity is king.

When it comes to any performance question in any system the answer usually boils down to "it depends".

If your performance problem is related to WRITES then a highly NORMALISED structure is best and you'll want that Junction table.  You'll end up writing a lot less data and that can speed things up substantially (though you may burn that advantage by having to do lookups before you create the inserts).  Reading from the individual normalised tables can be very fast too.

If your problem is related to analytical READS then a DENORMALISED structure is best.  Joins can be very performance intensive if the tables are large and the indices spread out.  You'll sacrifice a lot of space to gain a lot of time.

In general, you want to look at the specifics of your situation and weigh the pros and cons of each approach before deciding on a solution.  Personally, I've always found it better to focus on Clarity in the initial stages and refactor for performance if I discover a problem later.

Answer (score 4):

A many-to-many relationship exists in a relationnal model, it's just an abstraction of the mind.
When you'll implement it there will be a articles_to_tags table where you'll have :

fk_article(INTEGER)
fk_tag(INTEGER)

cf
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem in using Many to Many relationships. It is often required.

And yes, it is not possible to create a many to many relation, without using a third table.

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem with having a many-to-many relationship if that's what the data require, but you'll want a 3rd table to represent it.

Comment: I would say "you'll require a third table."