# Designing database

Tags: sql, database-design

I am finding it difficult to decide on an efficient design of the database. My application would get a number of ingredients(table) from the user and check with the database to find the recipe that could be prepared from the list of ingredients that the user provides.

My initial design is

```
Useringredients(ing_id,ing_name..);
```

the recipe database would be

```
recipe(rec_id,rec_text,...);
items_needed(rec_id,item_id,...);
items(item_id,item_name);
```

Is this a good way ? If so how will i be able to query to retrieve the recipes from the list of user ingredients.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Many questions about a database to store recipes, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225536/database-design-for-storing-food-recipes). I remember seeing a similar recent question about best matching of recipes with some of the available ingredients but I cannot find it back at this moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design could work. You have one table recording recipes, one recording items and one recording the many-to-many relationship between the two (though I would work on your naming conventions to keep things consistent).

To get any recipes that contain at least one item in your list, you could use the following:

```
Select rec.rec_id, 
       Count(itn.item_id) as [NumMatches]
From recipe as rec
Join items_needed as itn on itn.rec_id = rec.rec_id
Where itn.item_id in (comma-delimited-list-of-itemIDs)
Group By rec.rec_ID
Having Count(itn.item_id) > 0
Order By Count(itn.item_id) desc
```

This returns any recipes that contain at least some of the items that are selected, sorted with the first recipes having the highest number of matches.

Comment: Just to rephrase my question, consider I send a table of 10 items (userIngredients) and i want to know the recipes that could be prepared with some combination of those 10 items. Does not have to be all the 10 items, say just with 4 of those ingredients a recipe could be prepared.

Comment: I just modified the query. Now it will return any recipe with at least one match, and will order them so that the higher in the list, the more matches to items in your list.

Comment: thanks for the help. 
Seems like a pretty complex query to a beginner like me. Can you explain how it works ? What is NumMatches ? And what is comma-delimited-list-of-itemIDS) ?

Comment: NumMatches is a column alias that will be used in the query output - will allow you to reference the results by column name, if you need to. Comma-Delimited-List is just what it sounds like. If the itemIDs that you want to match are 1, 2 and 3, then your list is "1, 2, 3" (without the quotes).

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong : 
I guess there is one more step. Since ing_id and item_id are not going to be the same, as ing_id is going to be assigned as and when a new item is added to their list. 
Hence first find item_id corresponding to the ing_name and then use it for the query you provided.
Is that right ?? Will it be efficient then ?

Answer (score 0):

The following query should give you a list of unique recipes using any one of the ingredients the user searches for

```
select distinct rec_id,rec_text,ii.item_name
from recipe rr
join items_needed itn on itn.rec_id=rr.rec_id
join items ii on ii.item_id=itn.item_id
join userIngredients ui on ui.ing_id=ii.item_id
```

Yaakov's query looks like it will handle the situation where you want all ingredients.   You might be able to replace (`comma-delimited-list-of-itemIDS`) with `(select ing_id from userIngredients)`

Comment: Just to rephrase my question, consider I send a table of 10 items (userIngredients) and i want to know the recipes that could be prepared with some combination of those 10 items. Does not have to be all the 10 items, say just with 4 of those ingredients a recipe could be prepared.