# MySql database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many

Table `locations` contains `locID`, `lat` & `long` & name values of a certain location.

Table `categories` contains `ID`, `category-name` & `locID`.

How do I make categories assignable to multiple locations?

It doesn't make sense to have the same category stored multiple times, once for every locID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [many-to-many relationship in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273715/many-to-many-relationship-in-database-design)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to model the many-to-many relationship.

```
location_category
location_id   category_id
1             1
1             2
2             1
2             3
3             4
```

Add foreign key constraints to prevent invalid values from being entered into the table:

- From `location_category.location_id` to `locations.locID`
- From `location_category.category_id` to `categories.ID`

Also make `(location_id, category_id)` the primary key for the table to prevent adding a category to the same location multiple times.

---

When reading the data from the table, use JOINs to get the related data from the main tables:

```
SELECT ...
FROM location_category
JOIN locations ON location_category.location_id = locations.locID
JOIN categories ON location_category.category_id = categories.ID
WHERE ....
```

Comment: Huh, I don't really understand that, what kind of fields do I need to create to link the catyegory to the location?

Comment: Ah, got it, that's awesome, I just need a table (foreign key) to associate one key to the other, awesome! Thank you!