# Use multiple records for one record

Tags: mysql, database-design

Lets say I have a database with the following tables:

Table `movie` containing:

```
movie1
movie2
```

Table `actors` containing:

```
actor1
actor2
actor3
```

Lets say `actor2` appears in both movies `movie1` and `movie2`. How can I use this now without having to enter a different record for each now actor to give it its own movie id in the table `actors`, to save some space?

Comment: You are attempting to make a micro optimization.  Just use the database for what it is designed for:  normalized data and don't worry about duplicated data.

Comment: alright, thx alot for the fast replay ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273715/many-to-many-relationship-in-database-design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a junction-table  (link-table) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table):

(Just for the sake of it I set plural on both table-names)

```
tab movies 
      = movie1
      = movie2

tab actors
      = actor1
      = actor2
      = actor3

tab movies_actors
      = actors (id of tab_actors)
      = movies (id of tab_movies)
```

Then you could join tab_movies_actors with tab_movies and tab_actors to get which actors belongs to which movies:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_movies tm
JOIN tb_movies_actors tma ON (tm.id = tma.movies_id)
JOIN tb_actors ta ON  (tma.actors_id = ta.id)
```

or a specific movie:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_movies tm
JOIN tb_movies_actors tma ON (tm.id = tma.movies_id)
JOIN tb_actors ta ON  (tma.actors_id = ta.id)
WHERE tm.id = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a relationship "many to many" it requires a link table like the one that is shown in the previous answer.