# Foreign Key relationships are not making sense, is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I'm having an issue with trying to understand how my tables should relate in my database. I am a beginner and have tried to research on my own. The tables are below

```
    CREATE TABLE PIZZA
(
    pizza_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    pizza_name VARCHAR (255),
    pizza_desc VARCHAR (255),
    pizza_price DOUBLE
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    cust_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cust_first_name VARCHAR (255),
    cust_last_name VARCHAR (255),
    cust_street VARCHAR (255),
    cust_apt VARCHAR (255),
    cust_city VARCHAR (255),
    cust_state CHAR(2),
    cust_zip CHAR(5),
    cust_home_phone CHAR(10),
    cust_mobile_phone CHAR(10),
    cust_other_phone CHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE PIZZA_ORDER
(
    pizza_order_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    pizza_id INT,
    cust_id INT,
    order_date TIMESTAMP,
    order_quantity INT,
    order_notes VARCHAR (255),
    FOREIGN KEY (pizza_id) REFERENCES PIZZA(pizza_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(cust_id)
);
```

My question is, how would this work if a record in the PIZZA_ORDER table had let's say two different pizza, meaning two different pizza_ids? I was thinking of just making the primary key of PIZZA_ORDER not unique and having x number of records for each actual order. But I'm not sure how that would work. Thanks again for any light you guys can shed on this.

Comment: Your Pizza table needs a foreign key to the Pizza_Order table, you have it backwards

Comment: You, sir, have a many-to-many relationship there. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273715/many-to-many-relationship-in-database-design

Comment: @kittykittybangbang thank you, yeah I had a many-to-many with pizza and pizza_order. I guess in the future, I should try to avoid many-to-many if at all possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, don't be scurred! :) Many-to-many relationships, when handled properly, can be a beautiful thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Sales Order hasMany Sales Order Line Items

```
create table orders (
  id int primary key,
  ...
);

create table order_items (
  order_id int references orders(id),
  line int,
  pizza_id int references pizza(id),
  ...
  primary key (order_id, line)
);
```

Please see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831 to save time :)

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, I eliminated my many-to-many relationship and created an additional LINE_ITEMS table that referenced both the order and product. Then I only developed one-to-many relationships between the tables. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should rather have a relation between `pizza_order` to `pizza` table and between `Customer` to `pizza_order` table. It's like saying, every pizza is related to one/more pizza order; whereas every pizza order is related to one/more customer.

```
CREATE TABLE PIZZA_ORDER
(
    pizza_order_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date TIMESTAMP,
    order_quantity INT,
    order_notes VARCHAR (255),
    cust_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(cust_id)
);

CREATE TABLE PIZZA
(
    pizza_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    pizza_name VARCHAR (255),
    pizza_desc VARCHAR (255),
    pizza_price DOUBLE,
    pizza_order_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (pizza_order_id) REFERENCES PIZZA_Order(pizza_order_id)
);
```