# store in a database who's liked something

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

How should a database store who's liked a certain post?

Should I have a separate table which keeps tracks of all likes, and keeps every like of every post together, storing article_id, user_id, and like/dislike?

Comment: That kind of data usually stored in a graph db rather than a relational one.

Comment: This is (obviously) a(n easily found) faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [many-to-many relationship in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273715/many-to-many-relationship-in-database-design)

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a N-M relationship between users and posts, where each user might ligke serveral posts and each post can be liked by several users.

I would recommend using a bridge table, with foreign keys refering the posts and users tables.

In a nutshell, that would look like:

```
table: users
    user_id
    name
    ...

table: posts
    post_id
    title
    ...

table: users_like_posts
    user_id       -- foreign key to users(user_id)
    post_id       -- foreign key to posts(post_id)
    like_dislike
```

Comment: I'm trying to implemet similar schema, how can you suggest I index the users_like_post table.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be creating a table which trucks likes and dislikes:
Example:

Like and dislike could be boolean or anything else that you like to implement.

```
Table:Like
-----------------
id     |  post_id | user_id |  like_dislike     |
1      |  1234    |  13783  |      0            |
2      |  1234    |  12083  |      1            |
```