# organize a set of data based on open slots/sold-out slots

Tags: excel, database, database-design

I am trying to analyze data based on the following scenario:

A group of places, each with its own `ID` gets available for visiting from time to time for an exclusive number of people - this number varies according to how well the last visit season performed - so far visit seasons were opened 3 times.

Let's suppose `ID_01` in those three seasons had the following available slots/sold-out slots ratio: 25/24, 30/30, and 30/30, `ID_02` had: 25/15, 20/18, and 25/21, and `ID_03` had: 25/10, 15/15 and 20/13.

What would be the best way to design the database for such analysis on a single table?

So far I have used a table for each ID with all their available slots and sold-out amounts, but as the number of IDs gets higher and the number of visit seasons too (way beyond three at this point) it has been proving to be not ideal, hard to keep track of, and terrible to work with.

The best solution I could come up with was putting all IDs on a column and adding two columns for each season (`ID | 1_available | 1_soldout | 2_available | 2_soldout | ...`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [many-to-many relationship in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273715/many-to-many-relationship-in-database-design)

Comment: [help/on-topic] [help/dont-ask] [ask] [Help] [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would be a good starting point.

Based on the information you provided in your question, you create one table.

```
AvailableDate
-------------
AvailableDateID
LocationID
AvailableDate
AvailableSlots
SoldOutSlots
...
```

You may also have other columns you haven't mentioned.  One possibility is `SoldOutTimestamp`.

The primary key is `AvailableDateID`.  It's an auto-incrementing integer that has no meaning, other than to sort the rows in input order.

You also create a unique index on (`LocationID`, `AvailableDate`) and another unique index on (`AvailableDate`, `LocationID`). This allows you to retrieve the row by `LocationID` or by `AvailableDate`.