# How do I model Pages that can have an unlimited amount of subpages in Prisma

Tags: sql, database-design, model, prisma

So I want to create a Sidebar similar to Notion where you can make a Page with a relationship where it can have multiple subpages. I have no idea where even to start.

This is what I want
[image]

So far in my code, I have a model that looks like this.

[image]

I don't understand how can I make an unlimited about of pages related to pages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [many-to-many relationship in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273715/many-to-many-relationship-in-database-design)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a one-to-many relationship to the same object. You can do that, by adding an optional `parentId` and then defining the relationship:

```
model Page {
  id         String  @id
  title      String
  // ...
  parentId   String?
  parentPage Page?   @relation(fields: [parentId], references: [id], name: "pageHierarchy")
  childPages Page[]  @relation(name: "pageHierarchy")
}
```