# PHP/MySQL: Multiple comma separated values per table field vs... WHAT?

Tags: php, mysql, database-normalization, first-normal-form

Storing multiple comma-separated values in a single table field is a notoriously bad design as it impacts performance and breaks relationships. Except I don't know how to change things.

I have a movies table:

```
+------------------------------+
| id |       name       | year |
+------------------------------+
|  1 |       Alien      | 1979 |
|  2 |  Breakfast Club  | 1985 |
|  3 |    First Blood   | 1982 |
+------------------------------+
```

I need to store the genre(s). I need a separate genres table now that inserting it in the same table is a no-go. But how to structure it? I can only contemplate two ways: using foreign keys or boolean type fields, each with its own pros and cons.

**foreign keys**:

```
+---------------------+
| movie_id | genre_id | 
|----------+----------+
|    1     |    2     |
|    1     |    4     |
|    3     |    1     |
+----------+----------|
```

The problem here is a row per genre penalty. To store more than one genre I have to run multiple insert queries like this:

```
foreach($genres as $genre_id)
{
    $db->query("INSERT INTO genres (movie_id, genre_id) VALUES ('$movie_id', '$genre_id');
}
```

Isn't this an excess of db calls? It is the number of introduced genres. How else to do it?

**boolean type fields**:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+----------
| movie_id | adventure | comedy | drama | horror  ...
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+----------
|    1     |     0     |   1    |   0   |    1    ...
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+----------
|    3     |     1     |   0    |   0   |    0    ...
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+----------
```

Is this is better? This will let me run a single insert, except with complex query building:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO genres (movie_id, ";
$query2 = " VALUES ('$movie_id', ";
foreach($genres as $key => $value)
{
    if($value)
    {
        $query1 .= "$key, ";
        $query2 .= "'$value', ";
    }
}
$query = rtrim($query1, ", ") . ")" . rtrim($query2, ", ") . ")";
$db->query($query);
```

I don't know if this is practical.

I don't like either approach. What is a more elegant solution?

Comment: *"Ok, this is better. Or is it?"* - It's actually worse than comma-delimeted values.  Strings can at least be parsed/manipulated/etc. even if it's not great.  (Native JSON support has come a long way in many databases too, by the way.)  But storing **data** as **schema** (genres as column names) not only makes it difficult to **read** that data but requires you to **modify the schema** any time you want to change that data.  Your first idea looks like a standard many-to-many relationship.  Thinking that it "doesn't look pretty" isn't a valid technical reason to avoid it.

Comment: Unless a film is in dozens of genres, I wouldn't worry about multiple inserts for each genre. You don't add films so often that this overhead is significant.

Comment: David, I agree with you as to the problem of possible future modifications, I wanted to mention it too, but when it comes to reading alone it's actually better than the first one. Just saying. Thanks.

Comment: Barmar, it's just an example, the project I have in mind requires up to 24 values like that. So, I guess I'll have to stick with the standard design no. 1 and go for some tricks, prepared statements and whatnot.

Comment: [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [mre] PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help]

Comment: [many-to-many relationship in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1273715/3404097)

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware a single INSERT statement can insert multiple rows?

```
INSERT INTO genres (movie_id, genre_id) 
VALUES (?, ?),
       (?, ?),
       (?, ?)...
```

Alternatively, even if you do one row per call, you can use a prepared statement and execute it multiple times with different values.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO genres (movie_id, genre_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
foreach($genres as $genre_id)
{
    $stmt->execute([$movie_id, $genre_id]);
}
```

I would not recommend your second solution, storing genres as boolean columns. It's likely that you'll add new genres from time to time, and it's costly to run ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN every time you do that. Then you need to worry about how many columns is the maximum MySQL can support in a given table, etc.

Comment: Strangely, I wasn't aware of the first thing you said, no. But I guess I'll just have to stick with prepared statements, because I will have to use it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, here's another thing that's been bothering me about the first method. How do I go about updating the table? Suppose, I uncheck one of the genres somewhere using a form, what next? Delete all genres  and re-insert the currently selected ones? It seems easier than otherwise...

Comment: If you remove a genre for a given movie, then you delete one row.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. I mean I would do it using an html form with checkboxes. I don't see how this would allow me to remove just one row without running a comparison at least, which might be more costly than simply deleting all of it and re-inserting...

Comment: If the form submission has checked genres to keep, then you can `DELETE FROM moviegenre WHERE movie_id = ? AND genre_id NOT IN (?, ?, ?, ...)`.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. It didn't occur to me because I rely on php logic alone too much. But that means I will have to make this call unconditionally on every form submit? Unless, of course, there are errors and such. Not that it's a problem, just getting to the bottom of it.

Comment: You could make the Javascript front end detect if any boxes that were checked become unchecked, and pass another POST parameter called "delete_some_genres" or something. I.e., that param is false by default, and Javascript sets it to true if the user unchecks any box. But you might be trying to optimize needlessly. It's not like this form is going to be submitted every second, right?

Comment: No, not every second, but occasionally, several times a day. And I try to dispense with js for this project as much as possible. But thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about an action that happens several times per day. I think you're overthinking this.