# Relations between entities in ER diagram: can they have a key?

Tags: database, key, primary-key, entity-relationship, erd

Can a relation between entities have a key in an ER diagram?

Doing my assignment I added a primary key to a relation between two entities but the instructor didn't agree.

Comment: What do "have a key" & "have a key in an ERD" & "added a primary key" mean here exactly? This is extremely unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. There are many methods that are or claim to be ER. What textbook is your from? What is the DDL for the ERDs in this question? What does your textbook tell you to do & have you done it? [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)  [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: [many-to-many relationship in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1273715/3404097)

Comment: There are several close-votes as the question would lack clarity.  However, entity- relationshthip theory clearly defines what a key is ("an entity **key** is a group of 
attributes such that the mapping from the entity set to the corresponding group 
of value sets is one-to-one.") - and that a primary key is one of the keys.  Moreover, this is a genuine question for anybody starting to learn ERD, and unless it's a duplicate, it has a value for the larger community.

Comment: What do you mean by "relation"? Do you mean "relationship" as in Entity-Relationship, ie an association on ER entities, which is actually a tuple, or the common misuse of "ER relationship" as a relation/set of tuples? Do you mean relational model relation, as in a relational model table or as in relational model association on values, that a table represents? Do you mean, foreign key constraint, which "relationship" & "relation" are frequently (mis)used to mean? What's the actual word you mean & why? Please give the details of the example you are talking about. Please use text/DDL.

Answer (score -1):

[Entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) have a unique identity and have a primary key that uniquely identifies them. For an authoritative definition, see [Chen's foundational paper of ER theory](https://doi.org/10.1145/320434.320440):

> an entity key is a group of attributes such that the mapping from the entity set to the corresponding group of value sets is one-to-one. (...) In the case where several keys exist, we usually choose a semantically meaningful key as the entity primary key

Relationships are only defined by the entities they relate.  They do not have an identity on their own, as they do not exist on their own.  Hence, they should not have a key on their own:

> Since a relationship is identified by the involved entities, the primary key of a relationship can be represented by the primary keys of the involved entities.

There is however an exception:  the [associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) is at the same time a relationship and an entity.  As it is an entity, it should have its own primary key.  And as it's also a relationship,  it's a relationship with its own primary key.