# How to generically model many to many entity relationships in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a SQL database for maintaining D&D games which has tables for things like Characters, Items, and Locations. I want to start modelling the relationships between all these different entity types, such as the relationship a Character has with another Character, or the relationship a Character has with a particular Item or Location, essentially creating a graph of how everything in a game is linked together.

What I tried was initially starting from the perspective of Character relationships, creating a many to many join table that looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE character_relationships (
    character_id_from UUID REFERENCES characters(id),
    character_id_from_id_to UUID REFERENCES characters(id),
    relationship_type TEXT,
    opinion TEXT,
    -- Additional relationship-specific attributes
);
```

but if I want to be able to generically model relationships from any entity type such as characters to items, or items to locations, what's the best way of handling this?

I'm thinking I may need to create a "superclass" table called Entity, which is inserted into first to retrieve the ID, and then used to insert into the subclass Characters, Items, and Locations tables, with a resulting join table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE entity_relationships (
    entity_id_from UUID REFERENCES entities(id),
    entity_id_from_id_to UUID REFERENCES entities(id),
    relationship_type TEXT,
    opinion TEXT,
    -- Additional relationship-specific attributes
);
```

Is this the best way to design generic relationships or is there an alternative besides creating multiple tables for each relationship type? What would be the potential downsides of doing it this way?

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. A table represents a relationship/association. It holds the tuples of values that are so related/associated. Follow some published academic textbook(s) on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts or videos.) Dozens are online free in pdf & html. There are sometimes free online university/college courses. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.) Basic questions are SO Q&A already.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: [many-to-many relationship in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1273715/3404097)

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097)

Comment: I suggest you learn about [4th normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form). To implement this properly, create a separate table for each relationship.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin, it sounds like creating a separate table for each relationship is the way to go. 
I was trying to avoid associative polymorphism which is how I came to this approach of using a super table after seeing your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003042/6179452 and reading your chapter on associative polymorphism in SQL Antipatterns. It seemed like this resulted in much simpler queries and allowing for a single table instead of many tables. Are there particular reasons the super table approach is not favoured in this case?Thanks!

Comment: I've never been satisfied with the workarounds for polymorphism, even in my own book! LOL! Fundamentally, SQL doesn't model type hierarchies. It models concrete entities. I know some implementations extend SQL with some features that mimic inheritance, but they have limitations and add complexity to your queries that make them a net PITA.

Answer (score 0):

> but if I want to be able to generically model relationships
> from any entity type such as characters to items, or items
> to locations, what's the best way of handling this?

Don't go *higher-level* if you don't need to, stay concrete: just create one "join table" for every such relatioship.  The semantics stays direct and clear (you can see what entities there actually are), your queries also stay simple and to the point, as well as defining constraints remains straightforward.

> I'm thinking I may need to create a "superclass" table called Entity,
> [...] What would be the potential downsides of doing it this way?

The downside is that this is the opposite as above, it's extra-complexity at all levels, indeed most of the logic that is usually in charge of the DBMS would have to be coded manually, up to using triggers to ensure the consistency of the relationships (to ensure the relatioship_type is compatible with the referred entities, and similar).  So, this is simply not the way to go unless the domain does have an *open* collection of entity types.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, with its own pros and cons... 'best' is a hard word to quantify... seen and done this issue lots of ways for lots of reasons.

A single join table that uses composite keys for the related entities...
thing1, thing2, relationship_type, opinion... (not quite as abstract as the superclass Entity)

where thing1 and thing2 are composite keys like 'person:{guid}', or 'item:{guid}', or 'location:{guid}'.

Cons: As mentioned above in JDE's answer, your code takes on the work for maintaining the join table.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I challenge the notion that anything can have a relationship with anything.

The simplest way is to just define standard association tables between entities that can have relationships. Note also that this approach allows you to attach meaningful association data to that relationship - something that would be very awkward to do generically.

You could do it the generic way if you had uuids for all primary keys and had a single association table. Although there could be no proper foreign key relationships defined, it would work. But I don't recommend it.

The small initial effort spent doing it the normal way would be paid back many times over when compared to trying to bend the DB to your whim.