# Relational Database - How do you design SQL many to many relationship

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

What's the correct way to do (what I think is) a many to many association in a relational database?

Consider something such as (I'm using `sqllite` to play around):

```
# Store details about each teacher...
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teacher (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

# Store details about each student...
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (mentor_id) REFERENCES teacher (id)
    ...
);

# Store details about each available lesson...
CREATE_TABLE_IF_NOT_EXISTS lesson (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

# A lesson session is a record of a lesson having occurred (i.e. to track attendance)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lesson_session (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    starttime DATETIME,
    endtime DATETIME,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) REFERENCES teacher (id)
);
```

How do you add "many" students to a single `lesson_session` without duplicating loads of data? I'm assuming this is a many to many relationship because:

- Many students can attend a single lesson session.
- A single student can attend many lesson sessions.

Comment: no n:m would represented by a bridge table, which you don't have

Comment: Does this answer your question? [many-to-many relationship in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273715/many-to-many-relationship-in-database-design)

Answer (score 3):

You can have an intermediate table that represents a student taking a lesson_session.

```
student_id | lession_session_id
--------------------------------
0          | 22
1          | 22
0          | 15
0          | 35
```

For example here student 0 takes sessions 22, 15, 35.
Student 1 takes 22. Session 22 has students 0 and 1.

You can do joins to get the names of students/sessions later when it's relevant querying-wise.